# how to install gdb and valgrind in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 14.04, gdb

If I type `gdb` on my terminal prompt, gdb opens up , but when I run commands like next, weird stuff shows up like:

```
_libc_start_main (main=0x40060d <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfc8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdfb8) at libc-start.c:321 No such file or directory.
```

Same story with `valgrind`. Could somebody tell me how to install gdb?

Answer (score 14):

try this first:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg gdb valgrind
```

Comment: got this when i ran the command..Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6-dbg is already the newest version.
valgrind is already the newest version.
gdb is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.